# iOS MKMapView "Error Could not determine nearby locations"

Tags: ios, iphone, mkmapview, mkmapviewdelegate

I'm implement a MKMapView app and it works fine but I'm getting this error every time I install the app on my device for testing.

[image]

on the console I don't see any errors it all. any of you knows why of the error or how can this be fix?

I'll really appreciate your help.

Comment: Check the Settings app to make sure you're allowing this app to use locations.

Comment: Use the Map app to make sure this device _can_ determine your location.

Comment: @matt as I mention the app works fine. Can find the location of the user and drop a pin with no issues is just the error pop up with no more information but that.

Comment: What are you doing that causes the alert to appear?

Comment: Have you implemented the mapView:didFailToLocateUserWithError: delegate method? If so please provide the error.

Comment: @matt it was working with no errors until this morning. when start to showing up the error pop up.

Comment: @Marco Yes I did implement didFailToLocateUserWithError and I don't get any error it all

Comment: Does it help if you delete the app from the device and delete the app from DerivedData?

Comment: You need to determine whether it is your code or the system that is presenting this message. Search your code to see whether you ever present a UIAlertView whose title is "Error".